# How to merge href into click events

Tags: javascript, html

I have this href.

```
'<a href="index.php?imei=' + value['imei'] + '&nama=' + value['nama'] + '" class="summarykapal">Summary</a> '
```

this function

```
function getLastVesselPosition(imei) {
    $.goMap.setMap({zoom: 5, latitude: -2.226358, longitude: 117.48019});//heru
    google.maps.event.trigger($($.goMap.mapId).data(imei), 'click');//animasi select kapal
    $.getJSON("ajax/getLastVesselPositionById.php?imei="+imei, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            $.goMap.setMap({zoom: value['zoom'], latitude: value['latitude'], longitude: value['longitude']});
            google.maps.event.trigger($($.goMap.mapId).data(imei), 'click');
        });
    });
}
```

and this event

```
    $("a").click(function(event){
        if ($(this).attr("class") != 'infoclick') {
            getLastVesselPosition($(this).attr("id"));
        }
    });
```

when i do this

```
'<a href="index.php?imei=' + value['imei'] + '&nama=' + value['nama'] + 
                          '" class="summarykapal" onclick="getLastVesselPosition($(this).attr("id"))">Summary</a> ' +
```

then function isnt running, whats i missed?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by merging href into events ?

Comment: If u don’t want the link to fire, use event.preventDefault(). And if u want the href, it’s in event.target.

Comment: i want href to call the function

Comment: @HeruHandoko — `href` won't call the function. It's an attribute that holds a URL. **clicking** on the element will call the function (if you fix the syntax error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base on your answers,
 i've change my code into this

```
'<a href="index.php?imei=' + value['imei'] + '&nama=' + value['nama'] + '" class="summarykapal" id=' + value['imei'] + '>Summary</a> '
```

and this

```
$(document).on('click', '.summarykapal', function(e){
    // e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('infoclick') != 'infoclick'){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    //Un-comment below code in your script
    getLastVesselPosition($(this).attr("id"));
    }
});
```

thanks again, hope this will help others

cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
 onclick="getLastVesselPosition($(this).attr("id"))">
         ^                                   ^
         |                                   |
         |                                   End of attribute value
         Start of attribute value
```

Watch your quotes. Escape them or use different kinds of quotes when you want to use them in attribute values.

Better yet: Don't mash strings together to generate JavaScript inside HTML inside JavaScript. It's just a nightmare to maintain.

Use `createElement`, `addEventListener` and friends (or jQuery equivalents) instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, Js script below,

1. In your a tag dont have id but your passing **id** so it will gives **undefined**
2. In your function checking class but your asking id.

> getLastVesselPosition($(this).attr("id"))">Summary

you dont have id attribute but your passing.

```js
// Try edit message

let value = {}
value.imei = 'test1'
value.name = 'test2'

let data = `<a href="index.php?imei=${value['imei']}&nama=${value['nama']}" class="summary" onclick="getLastVesselPosition($(this).attr('class'))">Summary</a>`;
function getLastVesselPosition(id){
  alert('your class name :: -'+id)
}
$('#msg').html(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span id="msg">ttes</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below snippet with `.on('click')` method and checking `infoclick` class exist or not with `hasClass()` method.
I commented your `getLastVesselPosition()` function and alert `id` name on clicked.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.summarykapal', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if($(this).hasClass('infoclick') != 'infoclick'){
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
   //Un-comment below code in your script
   //getLastVesselPosition($(this).attr("id"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="index.php?imei='+value['imei']+'&nama='+value['nama']+'" class="summarykapal" id="id_abc">Summary</a>
```